# Why is the DataGridRow IsSelected binding not working on DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

In Josh Smith's MVVM demo he's uses a ListView with a ListViewItem style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomerItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1" />
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEEEE" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It binds the IsSelected property nicely. The style is applied to the ListView like so:

```
<ListView  
  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomerItemStyle}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
  >
```

**My Version**

I have tried binding IsSelected in a similar way with a DataGrid through DataGridRow. However it is causing issues when items are selected through the collection of item ViewModels, where the IsSelected property is defined.

As it is using a two way binding I would have thought that items could be selected through the UI and the collection of item ViewModels.

Let's say I select items through the UI, this works fine. I can select a singular item and then use [shift] to select a range, then using [ctrl] select some more items. Deselecting items works correctly as well.

However I select a bunch via the collection. Let's say upon the click of a button (as I do in the code below), a bunch of items get selected. When I scroll down the DataGrid then some are selected as they should be some are not. If I select one item through the UI then only some of the items are deselected and some remain selected, it's all a bit funky. Even the Select All button in the top left doesn't perform quite right.

**Code**
All code is below, at the bottom is the view the key piece there is the DataGridRow style with IsSelected binding.

Here is my user class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfAppDataGrid.Model
{
    public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static User CreateNewUser()
        {
            return new User();
        }

        public User() { }

        public int User_ID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Job_Title { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Phone_Office { get; set; }
        public string Phone_Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the UserViewModel, where IsSelected resides:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using WpfAppDataGrid.DataAccess;
using WpfAppDataGrid.Model;

namespace WpfAppDataGrid.ViewModel
{
    class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        readonly User _user;
        readonly UserRepository _userRepository;
        bool _isSelected;

        public UserViewModel(User user, UserRepository userRepository)
        {
            if (user == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("user");

            if (userRepository == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("userRepository");

            _user = user;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }
        public UserViewModel()
        {
        }

        public int User_ID
        {
            get { return _user.User_ID; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _user.User_ID)
                    return;

                _user.User_ID = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("User_ID");
            }
        }

        public string Username
        {
            get { return _user.Username; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _user.Username)
                    return;

                _user.Username = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _user.Name; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _user.Name)
                    return;

                _user.Name = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public string Job_Title
        {
            get { return _user.Job_Title; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _user.Job_Title)
                    return;

                _user.Job_Title = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Job_Title");
            }
        }
        public string Department
        {
            get { return _user.Department; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _user.Department)
                    return;

                _user.Department = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Department");
            }
        }
        public string Company
        {
            get { return _user.Company; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _user.Company)
                    return;

                _user.Company = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Company");
            }
        }
        public string Phone_Office
        {
            get { return _user.Phone_Office; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _user.Phone_Office)
                    return;

                _user.Phone_Office = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Phone_Office");
            }
        }
        public string Phone_Mobile
        {
            get { return _user.Phone_Mobile; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _user.Phone_Mobile)
                    return;

                _user.Phone_Mobile = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Phone_Mobile");
            }
        }
        public string Email
        {
            get { return _user.Email; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _user.Email)
                    return;

                _user.Email = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Email");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/sets whether this customer is selected in the UI.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _isSelected)
                    return;

                _isSelected = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my AllUsersViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using WpfAppDataGrid.DataAccess;

namespace WpfAppDataGrid.ViewModel
{
    class AllUsersViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        readonly UserRepository _userRepository;

        public AllUsersViewModel()
        {
            _userRepository = new UserRepository();
            _userRepository.LoadUsers();
            CreateAllUsers();
        }

        void CreateAllUsers()
        {
            List<UserViewModel> all =
                (from usr in _userRepository.GetUsers()
                 select new UserViewModel(usr, _userRepository)).ToList();

            foreach (UserViewModel uvm in all)
            {
                uvm.PropertyChanged += this.OnUserViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }
            this.UserCollection = new ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>(all);
            this.UserCollection.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> userCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> UserCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return userCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                userCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("UserCollection");
            }
        }

        RelayCommand selectItemsCommand;

        public ICommand SelectItemsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (selectItemsCommand == null)
                    selectItemsCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectItemsCommandExecute, CanSelectItemsCommand);
                return selectItemsCommand;
            }
        }

        private void SelectItemsCommandExecute(object parameter)
        {
            for (int i = 4; i <= 49; i++)
            {
                UserCollection[i].IsSelected = true;
            }
        }

        private bool CanSelectItemsCommand(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0)
                foreach (UserViewModel userVM in e.NewItems)
                    userVM.PropertyChanged += this.OnUserViewModelPropertyChanged;

            if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count != 0)
                foreach (UserViewModel userVM in e.OldItems)
                    userVM.PropertyChanged -= this.OnUserViewModelPropertyChanged;

        }

        void OnUserViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string IsSelected = "IsSelected";

            if (e.PropertyName == IsSelected)
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TotalSelectedUsers");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the user repository where I create the users:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WpfAppDataGrid.Model;

namespace WpfAppDataGrid.DataAccess
{
    public class UserRepository
    {
        ObservableCollection<User> _users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        public UserRepository()
        {
        }

        public ObservableCollection<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return _users;
        }

        public void LoadUsers()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 1000)
            {
                i++;
                var user = new User();
                user.User_ID = i;
                user.Username = RandomString(8, true);
                user.Name = user.Username + " " + RandomString(8, true);
                user.Job_Title = RandomString(8, true);
                user.Department = RandomString(8, true);
                user.Company = RandomString(10, true);
                user.Phone_Office = "07 " + RandomNumber(5200, 6700) + " " + RandomNumber(1000, 9999);
                user.Phone_Mobile = "04 " + RandomNumber(2800, 4500) + " " + RandomNumber(1000, 9999);
                user.Email = user.Username + "@gmail.com";
                _users.Add(user);
            }
        }

        private static Random randomSeed = new Random();
        public static string RandomString(int size, bool lowerCase)
        {
            StringBuilder RandStr = new StringBuilder(size);
            int Start = (lowerCase) ? 97 : 65;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                RandStr.Append((char)(26 * randomSeed.NextDouble() + Start));

            return RandStr.ToString();
        }

        private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            return randomSeed.Next(min, max);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is the view for all users:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppDataGrid.View.AllUsersView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:WpfAppDataGrid.ViewModel"
        Title="AllUsersView" Height="450" Width="820">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:AllUsersViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="UserRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="DGR_BackingBorder" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="1,2,1,2" Background="Transparent">
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="1,2,1,2" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="DGR_CellsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    <DataGridDetailsPresenter x:Name="DGR_DetailsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                                                          SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                                          Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" />
                                    <DataGridRowHeader Foreground="White" Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                                   Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,2,1,2" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkOrange"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Name="gridUsers" Background="Transparent">

        <DockPanel Background="Transparent" Margin="2,10,2,2" >
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0,2,4,2">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Content="Select rows 5 to 50" Command="{Binding SelectItemsCommand}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" Total: " />
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding  ElementName=GenericDataGrid, Path=ItemsSource.Count}" ContentStringFormat="0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <DataGrid Name="GenericDataGrid" Background="Transparent"  
                      RowStyle="{StaticResource UserRowStyle}"
                      BorderThickness="0" 
                      CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding UserCollection}" 
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" CanUserReorder="True" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=User_ID,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Username}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Title" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Job_Title}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Department}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Company}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Phone_Office}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mobile" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Phone_Mobile}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="eMail" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Email}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: do you have a sample project with this?

Comment: what is shown is the entire project

Comment: @Hank HI Hank! I know this is an old post. But you have accepted the wrong answer. In fact all posts are wrong. They suggest to disable virtualization implying or explicitly stating that your observed behavior is a bug. This is wrong. I came here because your post was referenced by another user to proof that your behavior is a bug and that the accepted answers provide a solution. In this context it would be nice if you un-accept the accepted answer as it will spread misinformation. Please refer to my new answer to learn how to "fix" the allegedly bug:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72927271/3141792

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hank

Disabling virtualization, will definitely fix your problem at a performance cost.

you could disable recycling of the VirtualizingStackPanel as @nit suggested, but that will not resolve the issue fully.

A different approach is to use Attached behaviours.

there is a tested working solution by @Samuel Jack (used it before), it is for listbox  and MVVM and it works great.
selected items are bindable in two way mode.

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html

As it's for ListBox, I uploaded a modified solution for DataGrid, It is a basic DataGrid with the desired functionality.

https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6837746_80955217_331798

Enjoy

Comment: This is a good example of why I always downvote answers by new users who only post links. I'd really like to see your solution as I am facing a related issue. But your answer is now worthless since the linked code is gone.

Comment: This is a bug in wpf.  The fact that the view is virtualized should not break the IsSelected data bindings.  It's been nearly 8 years since this answer was posted, and the bug still persists.  C'mon guys.

Comment: @JohnColvin This is not a bug. This is how UI virtualization works: the containers are completely removed from the visual tree and even reused for other items, which makes persisting the state useless. Also persisting the state won't come for free thus eliminating the performance benefits.

Comment: @BionicCode The state is persisted in the viewmodel, not the view.  Virtual or not, the view is not supposed to corrupt the state of the viewmodel.  It has been a while since I looked at this case, but I believe the bug specifically is this: when a virtual DataGridRow is unloaded, it unselects itself first.  The item wasn't removed from the ItemsSource, and the user didn't unselect it...yet it was unselected anyways.  Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @JohnColvin I obviously misunderstood the discussion. If your assumption is the common consensus i probably should post an answer. DataGrid behaves exactly the same way like ListBox: realizing containers involves updating their state. The binding engine will update binding targets the moment the Binding is set. DataGrid has several visual selection states e.g., focused and unfocused. By default, only the row header will give visual highlight feedback for the unfocused selection. You would have to override the default DataGridRow Style to configure different coloring for the unfocused state.

Comment: @JohnColvin I have posted an answer to proof that this is not a bug. The answer is intended to replace or fix the brutal misinformation that is spread by this thread. All answers got it wrong. I'm here because I followed a reference on another thread that was referring to this post as the solution. That's why I felt the urge to correct the misconception that the observed behavior is a bug that must be fixed by disabling UI virtualization. Such a recommendation will have a serious impact on many projects or developers that seek help. The spread of wrong information is a serious problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please, **do not disable virtualization!**
If this had been a bug, Microsoft would have fixed it long time ago as a data table is one of the most common data views in general.
The WPF framework is not a joke that targets amateurs and hobby programmers.   It is designed to be used by professional developers to tailor commercial rich desktop application. Such a critical bug, unfixed (i.e. not serviced) for that period of time, would instantly disqualify WPF as a serious and professional technology.

Everything is working fine.

You must set the `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the `Binding` on the `DataGridRow.IsSelected` property explicitly to `UpdateSourcetrigger.PropertyChanged`.

The `DataGridRow` has multiple visual selection states including unfocused selected. Unfocused selected is the state when the row is selected without focus, for example when being selected via the data model.

By default, the `DataGridRow` is actually selected, but the style defines no (satisfying) visual feedback for the unfocused state.

This "problem" is artificially introduced by customizing the visual states using simple triggers. It is another very good example why using the `VisualStateManager` is always preferred over a simple property `Trigger` (when visualizing the visual states of a `Control`).
Later frameworks like UWP enforce the use of the `VisualStateManager` (and `VisualState`).
The point is, that a control can have multiple states that are usually not expressed via properties. States are mutual exclusive which would require some extra effort when expressing this constraint via properties. `VisualState` is the convenient way to express visual states.

The following fully working example `Style` targets `DataGridRow` to show how to bind the `DataGridRow.IsSelected` property to a `IsEnabled` property of the row item (data model) and how to change the visual `Unfocused_Selected` state.

It is fully working, although incomplete, to proof the fact that the `DataGrid` is working as expected - with UI virtualization enabled. Just adjust the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` binding and ensure your data model has a `IsEnabled` property that raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event:

```xml
<DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}"
          Height="200">
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected"
              Value="{Binding IsEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal_Selected">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
              (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                              Value="DarkRed" />
                      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>

                  <!-- Unfocused related states -->
                  <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused_Selected">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
              (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                              Value="Orange" />
                      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>

                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver_Unfocused_Selected">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
              (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                              Value="GreenYellow" />
                      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>

                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver_Unfocused_Editing">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <!-- TODO::Define ColorAnimation -->
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>

                  <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused_Editing">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <!-- TODO::Define ColorAnimation -->
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>

                  <!-- Focused states -->
                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
              (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                              Value="CornflowerBlue" />
                      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>

                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver_Selected">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <!-- TODO::Define ColorAnimation -->
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>

                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal_Editing">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <!-- TODO::Define ColorAnimation -->
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>

                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver_Editing">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <!-- TODO::Define ColorAnimation -->
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>

                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal_AlternatingRow">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <!-- TODO::Define ColorAnimation -->
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

              <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                        ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                          Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"
                                          SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, 
        ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical},
        Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                    Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, 
        ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, 
        Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
              </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the op's question.  The problem is that a DataGrid (with virtualized rows) unselects rows as the user scrolls vertically.  Scrolling shouldn't affect any 'DataGridRow.IsSelected' binding source.

Comment: @JohnColvin Thanks for your valuable feedback! Scrolling selected item containers out of view i.e. virtualizing them does not result in lost of selection state (I have just tested it to ensure the posted code will work). I forgot to mention a subtle but important detail: you must explicitly set the UpdateSourceTrigger of the IsSelected binding to PropertyChanged. Additionally, I understood that the OP was observing strange selection behavior when the container is selected via the data model.

Comment: @JohnColvin However, following the above solution will allow the data model to persist the selection state when the container is virtualized and the DataGrid to restore it on container realization. Also Selection via data model works as expected.

Comment: It is a bug in wpf.  To repro, define a DataGrid with virtualization enabled and selection mode set to Extended.  Bind its ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection of unique row viewmodels and bind the DataGridRow.IsSelected property to the row vm in the RowStyle.  When you run the program, select some rows then scroll down a ways.  When you scroll back up, you should see rows which were previously selected are no longer selected.

Comment: @JohnColvin I can't reproduce it. At least not with my configuration/fix that sets the Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger explicitly to PropertyChanged.

Comment: This fixed my issue with scrolling the DataGrid and selections

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem with my DataGrid when scrolling.  The reason why it was causing weird problem was due to virtualization. Try setting virtualization to False in your DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="False">
```

Comment: I possibly have many thousands of records, so virtualization as much as a bother as it is, I still want to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Hank, your problem is that the Grid will only bind the visible `Rows` of the `DataGrid` and doesn't refresh the Binding as soon as another Row gets visible.

This issue is cause by the `Data Virtualization`.

Please try to setting Virtualization to `Standard`

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to catch the Scroll event and then attach to its items container generator to get the item generated while scrolling. When Item is loaded you can refresh the Binding (using BingingExpression) to the item so that it will reflect the state of your object i.e. IsSelected

Answer (score -1):

This is the problem with the `Recycling` `VirtualizingStackpanel`. Setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"` on `Datagrid` will solve this.